# SQL Server Recursive CTE to shred JSON: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: json, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am trying to rewrite a function to an inline Table Valued Fuction.
Database is SQL Server 2022.
Please have a look at the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/089b0/2). I tried multiple rewrites with explicit CASTs but it still wouldn't work for the key from the OPENJSON function. Running the query without that column however works as expected.

Can you please give any insight why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Thanks to @siggemannen for the solution: The collation of the key has to be changed as well.Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/089b0/11/0) to show the working solution.

Here's the example as code:

```
  DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'{"menu": {  
  "id": "file",  
  "value": "File",  
  "popup": {  
    "menuitem": [  
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateDoc()"},  
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},  
      {"value": "Save", "onclick": "SaveDoc()"}  
    ]  
  }  
}}  '
;
/* code adapted from Phil Factor 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/importing-json-web-services-applications-sql-server/
*/
WITH cteRecurseJSON AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(1 AS INTEGER) AS Depth, 
        --CAST('$' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS ThePath,
        CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS ThePath,
        CAST(@json  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS TheValue, 
        CAST('object' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ValueType
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        r.Depth+1 AS Depth,
            CAST(v.[Key] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS ThePath,
        Coalesce(Value,'') AS TheValue,
        CAST(CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN 'string'
                WHEN 0 THEN 'null'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'int'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'boolean'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'array' ELSE 'object' END AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ValueType
    FROM cteRecurseJSON r
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.TheValue) v
    WHERE r.ValueType IN ('array','object')

)
SELECT *
FROM cteRecurseJSON
```

Comment: Can you update the fiddle to show the query that works and the results you want from the query that doesn't?

Comment: Change to `CAST(v.[Key] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) collate database_default AS ThePath,` . Key has some weird binary collation which probably messes things up for you

Comment: The answer from @siggemannen is the solution! Thanks a lot...I would have never thought that this was due to collation.

Comment: @siggemannen Are you going to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `ThePath` in the anchor part needs to be `nvarchar(max)` and you need to change the collation [as noted by @siggemanen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237030/sql-server-recursive-cte-to-shred-json-types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and#comment136163799_77237030).

You should also use `STRING_ESCAPE` for correct escaping of paths. And you can simplify the `CASE` by just checking for an array.

```sql
WITH cteRecurseJSON AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(1 AS INTEGER) AS Depth, 
        CAST(N'$' AS NVARCHAR(max))  COLLATE database_default AS ThePath,
        CAST(jsonValue  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS TheValue, 
        CAST('object' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ValueType
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        r.Depth+1 AS Depth,
        CAST(
          r.ThePath +
          CASE WHEN r.ValueType = 'array' THEN '[' + v.[key] + ']'
               WHEN STRING_ESCAPE(v.[key], 'json') <> v.[key] THEN '."' + STRING_ESCAPE(v.[key], 'json') + '"' --got a space in it
               ELSE '.' + v.[Key]
            END
          AS  NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ThePath,
        Coalesce(Value,'') AS TheValue,
        CAST(CASE Type
                WHEN 1 THEN 'string'
                WHEN 0 THEN 'null'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'int'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'boolean'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'array'
                ELSE 'object' END AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ValueType
    FROM cteRecurseJSON r
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.TheValue) v
    WHERE r.ValueType IN ('array', 'object')
)
SELECT *
FROM cteRecurseJSON;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/DYNd2sE9)