# SQL - Find names of all nodes and nested nodes in a json file

Tags: sql, json

I received a few hundred thousand json files.  I have them loaded into SQL and parsing the data out into tables.

Is there a way I can find a distinct list of nodes/subnodes in the json file so I don't miss any obscure field that I hadn't noticed before?  For example:

I have these rows of data in my jsondata table:

```
{"id":"1", "images":[], "buyers":[{"nameLast":"SMITH","nameType":null,"nameFirst":"JOHN","nameMiddle":null}],"sellers":[{"nameLast":"ANDERSON","nameType":null,"nameFirst":"GEORGE","nameMiddle":"LEONARD"}]}
{"id":"2", "images":[], "organization":[{"orgName":"GROUP 1"}]}
{"id":"3", "images":[], "organization":[{"orgName":"GROUP 2", "city":"SEATTLE"}]}
```

Can I query my jsondata table to get a list of all nodes/subnodes, etc so I don't miss anything?

I'd like to produce a list like:

*id*

*images*

*buyers.nameLast*

*buyers.nameFirst*

*buyers.nameMiddle*

*sellers.nameLast*

*sellers.nameFirst*

*sellers.nameMiddle*

*organization.orgName*

*organization.city*

I found this query:

```
SELECT distinct [key]
from jsondata
outer apply openjson (filedata)
```

But it only gives me the root key/node names:

*id*

*images*

*buyers*

*sellers*

*organization*

Thanks!

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Do you use `SQL-Server`? `MySql`? etc

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241301/14868997

Comment: Also you seem to be ignoring arrays. What do you want for `$.sellers[0].nameLast`? Also what about keys that contain whole objects or arrays, for example do you want to see `$.sellers` at all, or only its sub-properties?